# Wondering what "so have" in this context really means

Tags: word-meaning

> The country’s main industry federation said the business community welcomed the result.
>   **So have** most newspapers, one calling it “a day of hope for all Egyptians”.
> <sub>Source: [Euronews.com, *Sisi Secures Crushing Win in Egypt Presidential Vote*](http://euronews.com/2014/05/29/sisi-secures-crushing-win-in-egypt-presidential-vote/)</sub>

Is this grammatical? Is it an expression? What does it mean?

Comment: *I love pizzas* ~ *So do I.*

Answer (score 3):

> The country’s main industry federation said the business community welcomed the result.
>   **So** *have* most newspapers…

Here, *so* is a pro-form.  It's used instead of repeating an earlier verb phrase ("welcomed the result"), and it adds the meaning "too".  It also triggers Subject-Auxiliary Inversion.

To paraphrase it, we can remove *so*, undo the inversion, put in the missing constituent, and add *too* to preserve the meaning:

> Most newspapers *have* **welcomed the result**, too…

Now we've paraphrased your sentence.  (Well, the first half, anyway.)